# Java 8 method references - dereferenced only once?

Tags: java, reflection, polymorphism, method-reference

I'm confused with method references. Consider the following script.

```
public class Main {

    static interface I {
        void m();
    }

    static class A implements I {
        @Override
        public void m() {
            System.out.println("A");
        }
    }

    static class B implements I {
        @Override
        public void m() {
            System.out.println("B");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A(); B b = new B();
        I i; Runnable r;
        i = a;
        r = i::m;  // static reference? might infere class
        r.run(); // prints "A"
        run(i); // also prints "A"
        i = b;
        r.run(); // prints "A" instead of "B"!
        run(i); // prints "B"
        r = i::m;
        r.run(); // now prints "B"
        run(i); // also prints "B"
    }

    public static void run(I i) {
        Runnable r = i::m; // dynamic reference, cannot infere class
        r.run();
    }
}
```

So it seems that:

- The compiler cannot inline method references because they are polymorphic. They are not resolved at compilation time, but at **runtime**.
- But `i::m` does not behave like `i.m()`...

So my questions are:

Are method references using **reflection**? And why they do **only once**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think about how this code would be written without method references, but with classes and objects, it all makes sense:

```
r = i::m;
```

is basically equivalent to

```
private class IRunnable implements Runnable {
    private I i;

    public IRunnable(I i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        i.m();
    }
}

Runnable r = new IRunnable(i);
```

So, if you assign another value to `i` after the IRunnable has been constructed, the IRunnable continues referencing the previous value, and calling its `run()` method again will still call the previous `i`'s method.

Comment: Yes it makes sense. But you must agree that it is also confusing, because this feature is now the exception to Java's polymorphic nature. (They're polymorphic but only once).

Comment: It's not the exception at all. Java always passes references by value, and method references are no exception. You're creating a Runnable from `i`, and the Runnable uses a copy of this reference.